# auto fill current page url to html form input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have html form using to send feedback by php email.
In one input I want to save url of current page. Where user hit feedback button. 
I want to track from which web page user is sending feedback.
Here is my code.
I found php code but its not working
Please help.

```
<input class="inputst" name="s_link" type="text" value="<?php $dataUrl = "http://".$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST].$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]; ?>" name="productlink"><br>
<input type="submit" class="inputbtn" name="submit" style="margin-top:30px; float:right; margin-right: 15px;" value="Submit">
```

Comment: im guessing you meant to echo, not assign to a variable?

Comment: Yes something like this. I am not sure. I just want current page url to be filled auto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
<input class="inputst" name="s_link" type="text" value="<?php $dataUrl = "http://".$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST].$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]; ?>" name="productlink">
```

Try:

```
<input class="inputst" name="s_link" type="text" value="<?php echo 'http://'.$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST].$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]; ?>" name="productlink">
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Awesome :) Don't forget to mark a solution as correct if they solve the problem for you -- that prevents them from showing up in 'Unanswered Questions', and awards rep to both the question asker and answerer :)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<?php echo "http://".$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST].$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]; ?>
```

you are assigning a variable instead of echoing it..